# Test for root node XML .NET

Tags: c#, xml, root

I'm currently using the code below to attempt to check for a certain root node (rss) and a certain namespace\prefix (itunes), but it seems to be saying that the feed is valid even when supplied with a random web page URL instead of one pointing to a feed.

```
FeedState state = FeedState.Invalid;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(_url);

XmlNode root = xDoc.FirstChild;
if (root.Name.ToLower() == "rss" && root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("itunes") == "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")
{
    state = FeedState.Valid;
}

return state;
```

Can anybody tell me why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution now. Putting xDoc.Load(_url); in a try .. catch block and returning FeedState.Invalid upon exception seems to have solved my problems.

```
FeedState state = FeedState.Invalid;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

try
{
    xDoc.Load(_url);
}
catch
{
    return state;
}

XmlNode root = xDoc.FirstChild;
if (root.Name.ToLower() == "rss" && root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("itunes") == "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")
{
    state = FeedState.Valid;
}

return state;
```